# Python percentile of recent value vs window of previous values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, percentile

Apologies I am a noob looking to transition from R!

Reproducible data example;

```
df = pd.DataFrame(1.26 + np.random.rand(size)/100.0,
                  index=pd.date_range('20160101 09:00:00',
                                      periods=size,
                                      freq='60s'),
                  columns=['ATR20'])
```

I would like to take a value in the column ATR20 and compute its current percentile against rolling window of the previous n values of column ATR20.

Heres as far as I got:

```
for n in range(1,len(df)):
print(sum(df.ATR20[n:n+20] > df.ATR20))
```

Which gives the following error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

I am sure that there is an easier way to do this with neater syntax but my searches haven't found anything close enough.

Thanks.

Comment: First, look at what you're trying to sum: if you got `df.ATR20[n:n+20]` to `df.ATR20` to work right, it would be a series of 20 bools, telling you for each value in `ATR20[n:n+20]` whether it was greater than the corresponding value in `ATR20`. So summing those bools is just going to count the number that are greater (because `True` and `False` and 1 and 0 when added as numbers). Is that what you were trying get as your first step? If so, it can be fixed to do that… but if it's not, please explain what you actually were trying to do with that first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will get what you're looking for. I used your example with only 10 elements in the dataframe and a rolling window of 3 elements, just so it is shorter when pasted here.

```
size = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(1.26 + np.random.rand(size)/100.0,
                  index=pd.date_range('20160101 09:00:00',
                                      periods=size,
                                      freq='60s'),
                  columns=['ATR20'])

#                         ATR20
# 2016-01-01 09:00:00  1.262522
# 2016-01-01 09:01:00  1.265116
# 2016-01-01 09:02:00  1.265051
# 2016-01-01 09:03:00  1.261109
# 2016-01-01 09:04:00  1.262699
# 2016-01-01 09:05:00  1.266710
# 2016-01-01 09:06:00  1.260186
# 2016-01-01 09:07:00  1.268001
# 2016-01-01 09:08:00  1.263227
# 2016-01-01 09:09:00  1.261331
```

You can use `df.rolling` along with `apply` to apply a function to a rolling window. I think the calculation I used here is more or less what you are looking for:

```
window = 3
df.rolling(window).apply(lambda x: sum([x[-1] > i for i in x]) / (window - 1))

#                         ATR20
# 2016-01-01 09:00:00       NaN
# 2016-01-01 09:01:00       NaN
# 2016-01-01 09:02:00  0.263665
# 2016-01-01 09:03:00  0.000000
# 2016-01-01 09:04:00  0.263932
# 2016-01-01 09:05:00  0.527632
# 2016-01-01 09:06:00  0.000000
# 2016-01-01 09:07:00  0.527024
# 2016-01-01 09:08:00  0.263754
# 2016-01-01 09:09:00  0.000000
```

Comment: Can you explain the code above? 

From what I understand i is the current value of ATR20 and x is the series of the size defined in the rolling function? The above looks right but to compute our rank as a percentile I think we should be dividing by the window size -1 not the x.sum.

Comment: I could be wrong on the equation, but what it's doing is taking each element of `x` (our rolling window of whatever size we specified) and adding it up if it is less than the last element of `x`, i.e. the end of our window. It then divides by the sum over all elements in `x`, so you are getting the percentile that the *value* of `x[-1]` represents. If you just sum 1 for all elements less than `x` and divide by the length of the window then I think that would be more of a percentile of the *rank* of `x[-1]`, which is cool if that's what you want. Let me know and I can update it.

Comment: Yes thats what I am looking for. Using your code with a slight mod gets me the desired results. 

`df.rolling(3).apply(lambda x: sum([x[-1] > i for i in x]) / 2)`

Comment: Updated my answer! Are you sure you meant to divide by 2? I would think you would want to divide by your window size. Or maybe `window - 1`?

Comment: Window -1 as the window includes the current selection.

Comment: Got it, answer is updated. If this worked for you, please mark it as "accepted" when you get the chance :)